# SQLAlchemy union_all and all() returning incorrect number of items

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For some reason when I'm using SQLAlchemy's `union_all` and `.all()`, it's returning the incorrect number of items.

As you can see below, I broke each one down to see where the error was. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

```
>>> pn = PostNotification.query.filter_by(notified_id=1)
>>> cn = CommentNotification.query.filter_by(notified_id=1)
>>> pn.count()
4
>>> cn.count()
2
>>> u = pn.union_all(cn)
>>> u.count()
6
>>> all = u.all()
>>> len(all)
5
```

Here are my two models:

```
class NotificationMixin:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    read = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    @declared_attr
    def notifier_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def notified_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class PostNotification(db.Model, NotificationMixin):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PostNotification {}>'.format(self.name)


class CommentNotification(db.Model, NotificationMixin):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post_comment.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CommentNotification {}>'.format(self.name)
```

**UPDATE**:

[Here is a screenshot of the data that represents the two models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHfo7.jpg)

When I define the columns explicitly, there is no issue when I'm using `union_all`. It only returns the incorrect amount of records when I `db.session.query(PostNotification)` and `db.session.query(CommentNotification)`.

```
pn = db.session.query(
    PostNotification.id,
    PostNotification.name,
    PostNotification.read,
    PostNotification.created,
    PostNotification.post_id,
    PostNotification.comment_id,
    PostNotification.notifier_id,
    PostNotification.notified_id).filter_by(
        notified_id=1)

cn = db.session.query(
    CommentNotification.id,
    CommentNotification.name,
    CommentNotification.read,
    CommentNotification.created,
    CommentNotification.post_id,
    CommentNotification.comment_id,
    CommentNotification.notifier_id,
    CommentNotification.notified_id).filter_by(
        notified_id=1)

u = pn.union_all(cn).order_by(PostNotification.created.desc())

>>> pn.count()
4
>>> cn.count()
2
u.count()
6
>>> all = u.all()
>>> len(all)
6
```

The problem with this, is I lose the model, and my relationships are gone. Therefore, I have to use this very ugly workaround. This only makes sense if you see the data in https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHfo7.jpg.

```
result = []
for row in u:
    if 'post' in row.name.split('_'):
        n = PostNotification.query.filter_by(id=row.id).first()
        result.append(n)
    if 'comment' in row.name.split('_'):
        n = CommentNotification.query.filter_by(id=row.id).first()
        result.append(n)
```

Now my `result` is in descending order, both tables are combined via `union_all`, and my relationships are back in tact. The problem now is, I obviously can't use result.paginate, because `result` is now a `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. I can now query `AbstractNotification` directly `db.session.query(AbstractNotification).all()`

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import AbstractConcreteBase   


class AbstractNotification(AbstractConcreteBase, db.Model):
    __table__ = None


class NotificationBaseModel:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    read = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    @declared_attr
    def notifier_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def notified_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class PostNotification(AbstractNotification, NotificationBaseModel):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'post_notification',
        'concrete': True
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PostNotification {}>'.format(self.name)


class CommentNotification(AbstractNotification, NotificationBaseModel):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post_comment.id'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'comment_notification',
        'concrete': True
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CommentNotification {}>'.format(self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The union `u` is not polymorphic in the sense that it'd recognize which rows represent `PostNotification` and which `CommentNotification` entities – it simply treats all rows as representing the primary entity `PostNotification`.

It also happens that you have 2 "identical" notifications in both tables, i.e. they have the same numeric value for primary key. SQLAlchemy deduplicates **model entities** based on primary key when querying, [as noted here by the author of SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083628/flask-sqlalchemy-different-record-count-for-count-and-all#comment24807506_17083628), and so `len(u.all())` returns fewer results. `u.count()` on the other hand counts *in the database* and so counts all rows. This deduplication does not take place if querying attributes or more than 1 entity.

Comment: What are my alternatives?

Comment: Your model looks somewhat like concrete table inheritance setup, but is not. Perhaps have a look if that's what you're after. SQLA has a [`polymorphic_union`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.util.polymorphic_union) just for that.

Comment: Not sure if that's actually the issue, because I tried losing the parent model, and defined the columns explicitly within `PostNotification` and `CommentNotification`. I'm still getting the incorrect number of records.

Comment: The detailed info did not change much. It is still happening for the same reason: a single model entity query will deduplicate based on primary key, and the union is not polymorphic, so `CommentNotifications` with equal id as a `PostNotification` are "deduplicated" (and comment notifications incorrectly loaded as post notifications). `Query.count()` on the other hand performs counting *in the database*, and sees the "duplicates" (as is explained in the linked comment).

Comment: I think I figured it out... see my answer. I'm not really sure why it worked, but it did, heh. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It works because now you're using an inheritance hierarchy (concrete table inheritance), and SQLAlchemy uses [`polymorphic_union`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.util.polymorphic_union) for you. It includes the identity as a literal select item and so the rows can be identified belonging to one or the other model. The selected entities are still deduplicated, but this time around there aren't "duplicates", and so the counts match. Note that you'd observe the count mismatch simply by taking union all with a table itself and selecting entities from it.

Comment: When I'd run `db.create_all()`, SQLAlchemy thought `AbstractNotification` was an actual table. I added `__table__ = None`, and it fixed the problem. Is that the correct way to go about that? That was the first thing I tried, and it worked - that literally never happens with SQLAlchemy, heh.